# Jenkins Shell script not working. Yarn: command not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins, devops

I am running jenkins to build a react app and executing shell commands to build the app automatically. I following are the bash commands

```
cd /var/www/FarmGroWeb
sudo git reset --hard
sudo git pull origin dev
sudo yarn
sudo yarn build
```

It fails on the yarn step. The error output

```
sudo: yarn: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Tried adding #!/bin/sh as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27243122/10003098) answer but this didn't work. What could be the workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Yarn is not installed or not on the PATH for jenkins.

- Install Yarn
- Check it's on Jenkins' $PATH, or provide the full path in the script (e.g. `/usr/bin/yarn`).